# Error Instantiating View Classes in Django

Tags: python, django, class, view, instance

I'm new to Django and have used generic views for all my projects so far. I've called them in the url.py code with

> patterns(r'^url$',DetailView.as_view())

However, now I'm trying to make my own class based views and am having trouble at it. I tried making a simple test where I call a model.py function from my view, but I get an error that I haven't instantiated an instance of the class. How should I instantiate the view class? Also, how come I don't get the same error when calling DetailView.as_view() the DetailView class isn't instantiated either, right?

My code:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def getBody(self):
        return self.body
```

view.py

```
class RatingView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "like.html"

    def __init__(self):
        model = Post
        template_name = "like.html"

    def modelFuncTest(self):
        return HttpResponse(self.model.getBody())
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.views import RatingView
from blog.models import Post

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/like/$', RatingView.modelFuncTest()),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your views.py to be just:

```
class RatingView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "like.html"
```

and change urls.py to be:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from blog.views import RatingView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/like/$', RatingView.as_view()),
)
```

and that should get you started, let me know if there are errors after making these changes.

There are some good examples in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) if you haven't seen them yet.

EDIT: Also, in the template, you should get your body like this:

```
{{ post.body }}
```

The beauty of the Class-based views is that the context of your object gets passed for you.

Comment: I know that this would work, but you never called modelFuncTest(), which is the problem I'm trying to solve. I know this example doesn't require it be called to work, but I'm trying to test calling methods from different classes on a smaller scale before doing more.

Comment: @Oblivionkey3 If you're trying to accomplish calling the getBody() function on your model, then in the template type {{ post.getBody }} and that will return your body. You shouldn't be doing that in the view.

Comment: If you're insisting on calling the function from your urls file, that's just bad practice and I don't have any comment on that :)

Comment: How would I call the function then? Like I said, I'm new to Django and I know how to make functions, etc. it's just that I don't know how I'm supposed to use them.

Comment: Also, from the research I've done, it seems that function based views are also fairly regular in django and not necessarily bad practice

Comment: @Oblivionkey3 correct, function based views are not bad practice at all, but this is a different issue. If you have the models.py like you have it in the question, and then the views.py and urls.py like i have it in the answer, in your "like.html" template, you will be able to call {{ post.getBody }} which will call the getBody function on your model. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to call the `as_view()` function on your class in your `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/like/$', RatingView.as_view()),
                       )
```

As for this:

> Also, how come I don't get the same error when calling DetailView.as_view() the DetailView class isn't instantiated either, right?

The `as_view()` function is a class method, which returns an instance of the view class that can be called when your URL pattern is hit.

Comment: If I call as_view() with the url, how do I call modelFuncTest()?

Comment: You don't, Django calls your view instance created from the `as_view()` call. That means you should change the name of `modelFuncTest()` to `get()`. You should probably read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/ or even start from square one with function based views (which are much easier to get started with) before tackling class based views. Also go back and look at the Django tutorial on views. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found some online resources and get it now